# Jquery Mobile and Backbone - Can't get history working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I've been trying all day to get my backbone routing working. It works when I navigate to the hashtag directly eg. index.html#schedule but on that same page a `<a href="#schedule"></a>` doesn't work.

I've tried this both before and after jquery mobile loads.

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

I've created a router and started the backbone history.

```
$(function () {
    var router = new MVC.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

But it's just doesn't seem to hook the hashtags links?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Update 1: I've found that I can get it to navigate during the scripting but the main problem is `<a href="#schedule"></a>` is not navigating. I think this must be something really simple, where jquery mobile is hooking link clicks.

Comment: I found that the hashchange event did actually have the mobile event still hooked. 
handler: function (){a.mobile._handleHashChange(location.hash)}

Comment: After even more explore-ring I've found that the hashchange event is never firing. It might be something simple like will a page hashchange even if there isn't a element with that id?

Comment: I've been play around more and debugging both jquery mobile and backbone and I've found that I can't even call router.navigate("jobs"). This is doing my head in :(.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pointless to fight against jquery mobile to get routing work with backbone, if this means disabling auto-ajax and other useful features.

Have a look at [jquery mobile router](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router), it's not exactly a backbone.router clone but it can be used to completely replace it in the jquery mobile environment.

My 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

Try only with:

```
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
```